# I am trying to extract text inside span_id, but getting blank output using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i am tring to extract text inside span-id tag but getting blank output screen.

i have tried using parent element div text also , but fail to extract, please anyone help me.
below is my code.

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 r = requests.get('https://www.paperplatemakingmachines.com/')
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
 mob = soup.find('span',{"id":"tollfree"})
 print(mob.text)
```

i want the text inside that span which is given mobile number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Data is actually rending dynamically through script. What you need to do is parse the data from script:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.paperplatemakingmachines.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
script= soup.find('script')
mob = re.search("(?<=pns_no = \")(.*)(?=\";)", script.text).group()
print(mob)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use Selenium as that text is not present in the initial request, or at least no without searching through `<script>` tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

url='https://www.paperplatemakingmachines.com/'
driver.get(url)

# It's better to use Selenium's WebDriverWait, but I'm still learning how to use that correctly
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.close()

mob = soup.find('span',{"id":"tollfree"})
print(mob.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of using regex to find the number

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.paperplatemakingmachines.com/',)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
r = re.compile(r'var pns_no = "(\d+)"')
data = soup.find('script', text=r).text
script = r.findall(data)[0]
print('+91-' + script)
```